# Shopify updating of shipping/delivery free programmatically during checkout

Tags: google-maps, shopify

Can shopify delivery/shipping fee be updated programatically during checkout? What I want to do for longer distance deliveries is use the Google API to calculate the distance difference between the my store and customer and increase the delivery fee if it is more than x miles (probably 10 miles).

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shopify's [carrier service API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice) for this. When a customer checks out, Shopify will provide your app with the line items and shipping address and your app can send back the shipping options and prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Carrier Service API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice) for that but you have to be on the [Shopify Advanced plan](https://www.shopify.com/pricing).

A possible hack would be to add a surcharge to the cart as a product. You'd have to get the customer to register/login in the cart and keep them from going to the checkout until you have a shipping address and then add the surcharge product via script.

You may need an app for that but the $220/month difference between Shopify and Advanced Shopify offers some incentive to look for alternatives.